# Set a number of files that will be written with INSERT statement

Tags: presto, trino

Is there a config for controlling the number of files written using INSERT or CREATE TABLE AS in Presto? Looking for something similar or identical to the Spark counterpart `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 1`.

I am looking to decrease the amount of small files that are generated with INSERT to avoid additional ETL in Spark with the above spark config. Is this possible? I haven't found anything close to this in Presto docs.

Answer (score 5):

You can't control the number of output files directly, but you can reduce the number of files that get written by turning on the `scale-writers` config option (or `scale_writers` session property). Add the following to the `config.properties` file:

```
scale-writers=true
```

When that option is enabled, Trino (formerly known as PrestoSQL) will use the minimum number of writers necessary and scale up as necessary based on throughput.

See this discussion on the [Trino Community Slack](https://trino.io/slack.html):

https://trinodb.slack.com/archives/CFLB9AMBN/p1564046069087800?thread_ts=1563945529.046400&cid=CFLB9AMBN

Unfortunately, this option is not yet documented as of Presto 327. I created an issue to track this improvement to the documentation: https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/2352.

Comment: Thanks so much! Will carry over comments/questions to slack.